# Field giving error after CF9 to CF10 Upgrade

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

We have a form which has some mandatory fields and 2 buttons(One is Submit, second is Search).
Search buttton code is like :

```
<input name="btnSearch" type="submit" id="Search" value="Search">
```

This code redirects to action form and then further to a new screen. Finally it reverts back to the main form and has code to restore the selected values.

One of the mandatory fields has the following code:

```
    <td align="right">Class Id:<font color="red">*</font></td>
    <td><cfselect name="YY_CLASS_ID" size="1" query="XX_Class_List"
value="XX_CLASS_ID" display="XX_DESCRIPTION" 
 required="yes"selected="#variables.XX_CLASS_ID#">
                                    <cfif variables.XX_CLASS_ID eq "">
                                    <option value="" selected></option>
                                    </cfif>
                                    </cfselect></td>
```

When user clicks on the search button and this Class ID dropdown is blank, they get an error that **"Error in YY_CLASS_ID text".**

yy_class_id field has required attribute as ‘yes’  and message attribute is not set. As per our understanding, this means error should always come if the user tries to navigate away from the screen without populating the CLASS ID.

However, as per our user ,they were not getting this error in CF9 and started coming after the CF10 upgrade. They are frequent users of the screen and could have not missed this in past if this was happening during CF9 days.

Can anyone please confirm if something has changed in CF10 which was not earlier in CF9 and causing this issue. Or we missing something here.
Let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors? I strongly suspect it's a case that on CF9 you had your `/CFIDE/scripts` directory exposed as web-browseable, and on CF10 you do not. For `<cfform>` functionality to work, you need to have `/CFIDE/scripts` web-accessible. You should, however, never rely solely on client-side validation for form-field validation, you should also have appropriate input handling on the server side too.

Comment: Thanks for ur response but this doesnt seem to be a JS error.In the above code for the dropdown field, if i change the required="yes" attribute to "no", error gets resolved. But during upgrade no code change happened, and my user says he never got the error in past. So was wondering if there is something that could be supressing the error in past and not happening nw.

Comment: So, you are saying that when the users click the 'search' button and a required field is not populated, they receive an error? I think the best way to fix this is to stop using `cfselect` and any other form/UI elements in ColdFusion. Often times, they lead to odd issues (such as this). Do yourself a favor, learn how to use form fields the *right* way and get rid of `cfform` and all its child tags.

Comment: Why do you have two submit buttons?  Maybe radio buttons would be a better way to offer that choice to the user.

Comment: Thanks SCott and Dan. This was my first reaction on seeing the code.However I am just maintaining it, not the creator .